# Should meta tags along with site verification, publisher be used on mobile website as well

Tags: seo, mobile, meta-tags

I have a website with it's mobile redirection to `http://m.example.com`. They both are different website which share a same database and URL structure. Apart from couple of URLs, all redirect to the correct `http://m.` version

My main website has all the required meta tags along with publisher and verification snippets. Since, the mobile website is completely different, I have used all those meta tags, verification snippet and publisher on that too.

Is this the right practice or I should remove meta and other things from mobile website?

Also, in addition I want to know whether to apply rich data structuring to mobile pages too or it isn't required. As of now structured data remains only on the main website

Comment: What do you mean by "the mobile website is completely different"? Is the content different or just the elements on the pages are smaller since it is on a mobile site? Would you be able to identify a 1:1 mapping between content and elements on the m. and desktop versions of your website?

Comment: contents are similar with different design(adapting to mobile). it's just that both are different asp.net mvc projects. ExampleSite , ExampleMobileSite . Both having their own but similar controllers, actions, models etc.

Comment: Why don't you go for responsive website, you don't need to have different design, and everything is resolved.

Comment: I am thinking on those lines but it might take more time as i need to study how to do that. So just wanted to know about meta tags for my current situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [responsive design](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/responsive-design) or [dynamic serving](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/dynamic-serving), you don't need to do anything. If you're using [separate mobile URLs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls), you'd have the `rel=canonical` set to the desktop version, so that would take care of it.

Comment: is this important to do this in the head tag or will the rel="canonical" work in body of the html too??

Comment: Like all meta-tags that affect indexing, you need to use them in the `head` .

Comment: thanks for clearing the doubt. Since my website has a master layout, i was about to add the `rel=canonical` in the body of pages

Comment: Remember to add also the rel=alternate on the desktop version, as the Google guide on "separate mobile URLs" suggest.